# Where am I wrong setOnClickListener is always in red

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android studio and tried a tutorial where the presenter demonstrated his program but when I type out the code I am persistently getting an error like Cannot resolve Symbol setOnClickListener where the setOnClickListener is highlighted in red.

```
TextView Resultant = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Resultant);
 EditText Percentage_Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Percentage_Input);
 EditText Number_Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Percentage_Input);

@Override
public View findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    return super.findViewById(R.id.Percentage_Input);
}

Button  calc_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc_btn);
calc_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick((View) view); {

        float percent = Float.parseFloat(Percentage_Input.getText().toString());
        float dec = percent/100;
        float Qty = Float.parseFloat(Number_Input.getText().toString());
        float total = dec*Qty;
        Resultant.setText(Float.toString(total));


    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is not in the right place. I see you are overriding `findViewById` (I wonder why) and rest of your code is also at the same level. You need to put all this code within a lifecycle method.

Maybe in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView Resultant = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Resultant);
    EditText Percentage_Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Percentage_Input);
    EditText Number_Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Percentage_Input);
    Button calc_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc_btn);
    calc_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick((View) view); {

            float percent = Float.parseFloat(Percentage_Input.getText().toString());
            float dec = percent / 100;
            float Qty = Float.parseFloat(Number_Input.getText().toString());
            float total = dec * Qty;
            Resultant.setText(Float.toString(total));

        }
    });
}
```

Also you are missing a semicolon `;` at the end of setting `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Move ; and put at the end, this:

```
TextView Resultant = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Resultant);
 EditText Percentage_Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Percentage_Input);
 EditText Number_Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Percentage_Input);

@Override
public View findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    return super.findViewById(R.id.Percentage_Input);
}

Button  calc_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc_btn);
calc_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick((View) view) {

        float percent = Float.parseFloat(Percentage_Input.getText().toString());
        float dec = percent/100;
        float Qty = Float.parseFloat(Number_Input.getText().toString());
        float total = dec*Qty;
        Resultant.setText(Float.toString(total));


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove you method findViewById, this is some weird stuff, returning always the same view.

Put the rest of your code inside onCreate and add the missing ; at the end.